# Given a convergent alternating series, what conditions can be placed on the terms in the summand?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I have a sum $$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^na_n$$ which I know to be convergent--in fact, $S\leq 1$. I additionally know that $\forall n,\ a_n > 0$. Given finiteness of $S$, what conditions can be placed on the terms $\{a_n\}$?

This question is answered the other direction in a multitude of posts, which generally appeal to either instances or counterexamples to the alternating series test. However, it is not clear to me what, if any, conditions can be placed on the terms given convergence of the series.

For completeness, I will mention that in the context of this problem we can consider a deformation: $S(s) = \sum (-1)^n a_n s^n $ should also be finite for $\forall s > 0 $. I selected the $s=1$ case for convenience, but perhaps properties (unbeknownst to me) of this deformation allow for more constraints to be placed on the $a_n$.

Comment: Are you sure you mean all $s > 0$? That would be a very strong condition; it would imply, for example, that the $a_n$ decay faster than any exponential, and that condition is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Yes, it should hold for any positive $s$. Can you explain the origin of your claim?

Comment: In order for a series to converge its terms must go to zero. So if $\sum (-1)^n a_n s^n$ converges then $|a_n s^n|$ must go to zero. This means $a_n$ decays faster than $\frac{1}{s^n}$ for any $s > 0$, which is a strong constraint, much stronger than the constraint that the series converges just for $s = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

A few considerations... Not sure this is what you're looking for though!

- For sure the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is converging to $0$.
- In case of alternating series, $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing.
- However, $\{a_n\}$ may not even be eventually decreasing.
- $\sum (-1)^na_n$ may be absolutely convergent or not.
- If not, reordering the terms, you can let the sum be equal to whatever you want.

Comment: What is meant by your second bullet--"in case of alternating series"?

Comment: Just a rewording of what an alternating series is.